# Equality in Z_n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is the following equality true?

$(kx+k\alpha) \text{mod 1} = k(x+a \text{ mod 1}) \text{ mod1}$?

I have reviewed some number theory books but I don't find how to justify that equality. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $\mod n$? You've written $\mod 1$. For that, equality is trivial

Comment: Please explain why.

Comment: $a = b \mod \! \! n$ means that $n | (a-b)$. So for any integers $x$ and $y$, $x = y \mod \! \!1$. Unless I've misunderstood the question?

Comment: I fear that you are thinking of "mod" as an operation.

Comment: @Praneet, it doesn't say anywhere $x$ and $a$ are integers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It appears i did misunderstand. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of modulo: We have that for any $a \in Z$, $a=1*a$, and so $(a \mod{1}) = a$. Thus,

$(kx+ka) = (kx+ka) \mod{1} = kx+ka = k(x+a) = k(x+a \mod{1}) = k(x+a \mod{1}) \mod{1}$